# Some images cannot be passed to imageview.image, why?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xml, image, uiimage

Parsing xml data from a table view to a detail view, I pass data to `imageview.image`. Some images appear in view, some not.

When I debug, `imageview.image` is sometimes `nil` and sometimes an image object.

```
 imageview.image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:sharedDelegate.imagObj]]];
```

This is the code in `viewdidload`.

In link all are jpg file only.

Comment: http://www.cinejosh.com/rss-feed/4/telugu.html this is the link @juvvamahesh

Comment: If possible use a method with an error parameter so you can obtain information on a failure. In this case use: `dataWithContentsOfURL: options:error:`.

Comment: i got exception sigbat ,resong:  [_NSPlaceholderData initWithContentsOfURL:options:error:]: nil URL argument'

Comment: What was the error message? The point of having an error parameter is to get the error information. If you get nil then there was an error, in that case display the  error: `NSLog(@"error: %@", error)`.

Comment: ya got solution for that the error is in url there is a free space.

Comment: NSString *spaceStrObj=[sharedDelegate.imagObj stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]; this method so i solved.thank you for your advice.

Comment: nil URL argument' this is i got error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `dataWithContentsOfURL` the official [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSData_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSData/dataWithContentsOfURL:) sounds:

> This method is ideal for converting data:// URLs to NSData objects, and can also be used for reading short files synchronously. If you need to read potentially large files, use inputStreamWithURL: to open a stream, then read the file a piece at a time.

Comment: how can i write this inputStreamwithURL in the method.

Comment: Here is a good example: http://samplecodebank.blogspot.hu/2013/05/nsinputstream-inputstreamwithurl.html

Comment: The important part of the documentation is the following sentence: "If you need to know the reason for failure, use `dataWithContentsOfURL:options:error:`".